# how do you subset data frame beteen times in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame called df:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1468555240, 1468555242, 1468555246, 
1468569649, 1468555251, 1468555257, 1468641020, 1468641021, 1468641021, 
1468641021, 1468641021, 1468641021), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), sCpu = c(7.28602, 9.49307, 7.70778, 8.51675, 6.97994, 
8.46983, 4.14684, 2.51154, 3.27359, 1.84363, 2.47815, 3.29061
)), .Names = c("Date", "sCpu"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I like to get the data points between only from 12 noon to 23:59, midnight. I don't want any data points after midnight to 12 noon. How would I do this in R?

I've tried creating a time column called T and did this:

```
subset(df, T<times(c("23:59:00"))&T>times(c("12:00:00"))
```

04:00 still shows up on my final subsetted data, any ideas how could do this?

Comment: There is nothing between 12 and midnight in the data frame you posted above. Is that the right dataframe?

Comment: @thepule there is data from 23:, it should be included in the subset data.

Comment: No, @thepule is correct, it's not in the subset.

Comment: @mkt Actually, OP is correct

Comment: @Hack-R I suspect this may be because we are in different time zones and OP didn't specify one.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
library(lubridate)

dfsub <- df[hour(df$Date)>11,]
```

However, your data has no values in that time range. Here's a working example with new data:

```
dat <- data.frame(datetime = seq(ymd_hms('2014-07-17 12:00:00'),
                                         ymd_hms('2014-07-18 11:00:00'),
                                         by = 'hours'),
                      misc = seq(1, 24))
datsub <- dat[hour(dat$datetime)>11,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since hour can only go from 0 to 23 we can simply check that the hour is 12 or more.  No packages are used.

```
df[as.POSIXlt(df$Date)$hour >= 12, ]
```

or

```
subset(df, as.POSIXlt(Date)$hour >= 12)
```

or

```
df[format(df$Date, "%H") >= 12, ]
```

or

```
subset(df, format(Date, "%H") >= 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
ps <- as.POSIXlt(df$Date)
subset(df, ps$hour>11 & ps$hour<=23)
# OR
df[ps$hour>11 & ps$hour<=23,]

                  # Date val
# 2  2013-08-02 14:01:21   2
# 3  2013-08-02 16:02:43   3
# 4  2013-08-02 18:04:05   4
# 5  2013-08-02 20:05:27   5
# 6  2013-08-02 22:06:49   6
# 14 2013-08-03 14:17:43  14
# 15 2013-08-03 16:19:05  15
# 16 2013-08-03 18:20:27  16
# 17 2013-08-03 20:21:49  17
# 18 2013-08-03 22:23:10  18
# 26 2013-08-04 14:34:05  26
# 27 2013-08-04 16:35:27  27
# 28 2013-08-04 18:36:49  28
# 29 2013-08-04 20:38:10  29
# 30 2013-08-04 22:39:32  30
# 38 2013-08-05 14:50:27  38
# 39 2013-08-05 16:51:49  39
# 40 2013-08-05 18:53:10  40
# 41 2013-08-05 20:54:32  41
# 42 2013-08-05 22:55:54  42
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1375437600, 1375444881.81818, 
1375452163.63636, 1375459445.45455, 1375466727.27273, 1375474009.09091, 
1375481290.90909, 1375488572.72727, 1375495854.54545, 1375503136.36364, 
1375510418.18182, 1375517700, 1375524981.81818, 1375532263.63636, 
1375539545.45455, 1375546827.27273, 1375554109.09091, 1375561390.90909, 
1375568672.72727, 1375575954.54545, 1375583236.36364, 1375590518.18182, 
1375597800, 1375605081.81818, 1375612363.63636, 1375619645.45455, 
1375626927.27273, 1375634209.09091, 1375641490.90909, 1375648772.72727, 
1375656054.54545, 1375663336.36364, 1375670618.18182, 1375677900, 
1375685181.81818, 1375692463.63636, 1375699745.45455, 1375707027.27273, 
1375714309.09091, 1375721590.90909, 1375728872.72727, 1375736154.54545, 
1375743436.36364, 1375750718.18182, 1375758000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), val = 1:45), .Names = c("Date", "val"
), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1468555240, 1468555242, 1468555246, 
                                  1468569649, 1468555251, 1468555257, 1468641020, 1468641021, 1468641021, 
                                  1468641021, 1468641021, 1468641021), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                 "POSIXt")), sCpu = c(7.28602, 9.49307, 7.70778, 8.51675, 6.97994, 
                                                      8.46983, 4.14684, 2.51154, 3.27359, 1.84363, 2.47815, 3.29061
                                 )), .Names = c("Date", "sCpu"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")


df$Date <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df$Date)
df$hour <- lubridate::hour(df$Date)

# Between noon and midnight
df[df$hour > 12 & df$hour <= 23,] # note - if there were more than 1 date you'd use ymd_hms for the filter
```

> ```
>                   Date    sCpu hour
> 7  2016-07-15 23:50:20 4.14684   23
> 8  2016-07-15 23:50:21 2.51154   23
> 9  2016-07-15 23:50:21 3.27359   23
> 10 2016-07-15 23:50:21 1.84363   23
> 11 2016-07-15 23:50:21 2.47815   23
> 12 2016-07-15 23:50:21 3.29061   23
> ```

Comment: Isn't the df$hour <= 23 redundant in this case?

Comment: @mkt No, that's how you filter it being before midnight. None of his data went passed that, but I'm explaining the concept.

Comment: I understand the explanatory value, but df$hour > 12 should be a sufficient condition here because midnight is 00:00, not 24:00, unless I'm mistaken.